# How to fix SIGSEGV? (Error while dealing with large values upto 1000000 in Fibonacci Series)

Tags: c, fibonacci, segmentation-fault

Tried to develop a code that quickly finds Fibonacci values.
But the problem is I get SIGSEGV error when input is of order 1000000.
Also from other questions around here I came to know that it may be because of stack memory that exceeds limit during runtime. And I guess that is the case here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
unsigned long long int a[1000001] = {0};
unsigned long long int fib(int n)
{
    unsigned long long int y;
    if(n==1 || n==0)
        return n;
    if (a[n] != 0)
        return a[n];
    else
    {
      y=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
      a[n] = y;
    }
    return y;
}
main()
{
    int N;
    unsigned long long int ans;
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 1;
    scanf(" %d",&N);
    ans = fib(N+1);
    printf("%llu",ans);
}
```

How do I fix this code for input value of 1000000?

Comment: Make it iterative instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better approach (which can still be significantly improved) that will calculate Fibonacci numbers for you:

```
unsigned long long Fibonacci(int n)
{ 
    unsigned long long last[2] = { 0, 1 }; // the start of our sequence

    if(n == 0)
        return 0;

    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        last[i % 2] = last[0] + last[1];

    return last[n % 2];
}
```

However, you are not going to be able to calculate the [millionth Fibonacci number](http://www.upl.cs.wisc.edu/~bethenco/fibo/) with it, because that number is much, much, much, much larger than the largest number that can fit in an `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the stack, use your own variables to track state. Essentially, do the function calls and returns with your own code.

The best way really is just to switch the algorithm entirely to one that's efficient. For example, to calculate fib(6), your code calculates fib(4) twice, once when fib(5) asks and once when fib(6) asks.